# Approach or tools to transform raw data into usable formats - Data Consolidation, Data Preparation

Tags: data-warehouse, data-wrangling, data-preprocessing

We are working on data preparation activity for a Datawarehousing project to build an enterprise level data warehouse. As an intermediate layer, we are bringing all the source database information into Hadoop datalake as hive tables.

In our use case, we have around 3000+ source tables. We would like to consolidate the  source data into a new schema in bigdata datalake. As part of this, we need to do the data profiling / data preparation for all the source database tables by analysing each and every columns to map/group into the respective meaningful destination table.

Requesting suggesting from the experts on any tools (open source or licensed) to easy the process.

Thanks,
Sakthivel

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few questions to better understand the use case -

1. Does the preparation requires joins?
2. SQL / NoSQL?
3. Cloud (Which one?) / On-prem?
4. Can the process happen in real-time?

Comment: HI Yaniv.. Thanks for your response..

Comment: Does the preparation requires joins? - No
SQL / NoSQL? SQL
Cloud (Which one?) / On-prem? - On Prem - MySQL and HIve
Can the process happen in real-time? One time and Need basis

Comment: As a result of this profile output, we should know whether the column is usable/non-usable, High/Medium/Low/Not Required kind of classification. This process should go automatically as we have 2000+ tables and if each has 20 columns avg, it has to be 40,000 + columns read and evaluation. Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about performing a SQL-based transformation over your MySQL and then migrating or copying the data to the DWH?